# 504 error PHPMYADMIN "1,401,446" records in table one and 100k plus in joining tables

Tags: phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am trying to retrieve data from multiple table with joins.

```
SELECT customer.customer_id,customer.email,push_messages.title, push_messages.text,push_messages.created_at,DATE(push_messages.delivered_at) AS pda, PDM.status,PDM.is_read,PDM.is_displayed, PDM.delivered_at,PDM.migastats_read_timestamp,PDM.migastats_read_timestamp
FROM customer
JOIN push_customer_message ON customer.customer_id=push_customer_message.customer_id
JOIN push_messages ON push_customer_message.message_id=push_messages.message_id
JOIN push_delivered_message AS PDM ON push_customer_message.message_id=PDM.message_id
JOIN migafunnelv2_customer ON migafunnelv2_customer.message_id=PDM.message_id
WHERE push_messages.app_id=311 AND customer.app_id= 311
AND push_messages.status LIKE 'delivered'
ORDER BY DATE(push_messages.delivered_at),push_customer_message.customer_id, push_messages.title
```

**push_delivered_message** have 1,401,446 rows,

**customers & push_messages** both have 10k plus rows each

When i run query even direct in phpmyadmin it gives error

> 504 Gateway time out

**DB SERVER**

- Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
- Server type: MariaDB
- Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
- Server version: 10.3.21-MariaDB - MariaDB Server
  - Protocol version: 10

How can i get rid of this error?

Comment: You would need to increase timeout parameters in nginx, php fpm and phpMyAdmin
I hope someone has a more detailed answer than mine

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some composite/covering indexes would speed it up enough to avoid the timeout:

```
push_messages:  (status, app_id, message_id)
push_customer_message:  (customer_id, message_id)
push_customer_message:  (message_id, customer_id)
customer:  (app_id, customer_id, email)
PDM:  (message_id)
migafunnelv2_customer:  (message_id)
```

If you need to discuss further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables.